# Swift 3 import CommonCrypto

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, commoncrypto, objc-bridging-header

How to import the Obj-C CommonCrypto library to an existing Swift Xcode Project (Swift 3, Xcode 8.3.3)?

I tried to create my own Objective-C bridging file and it wasn't working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know there are similar questions on stackoverflow about this but I looked at them and still had problems so I wanted to share my experiences.

Easiest way to import the Obj-C CommonCrypto library to an existing Swift XCode Project (Swift 3, Xcode 8.3.3):

1. Add a new file of type "Objective-C file".  It doesn't matter what you call it, you will delete it in a moment.
2. After you add that file Xcode should prompt you if you want to create a bridging header.  Check the appropriate targets for you project and allow Xcode to create the bridging header for you.
3. Add #import < CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h > to the bridging header(s) it creates.
4. Delete the Objective-C file you created in step 1.

I tried to create my own Objective-C bridging file and it wasn't working.  I spent about an hour looking for solutions until I tried this.  I wanted to share to hopefully spare other developers the issue I had.

Comment: Even though the question was a duplicate, your answer helped me!

Comment: This is way better than creating Aggregate target.